# CorsFilter setAllowedOrigins(*) redundancy

Tags: java, restlet

Is there any reason to write

```
corsFilter.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("*")));
```

where the definition of `allowedOrigins` in the Restlet framework is

```
private Set<String> allowedOrigins = SetUtils.newHashSet("*");
```

Another question - when I write the above line, I get an error running my app.
For some reason I get duplicate origin, and the client refuses to accept it - in the request I can see "*" and the domain name where I sent the request from.

How does this duplication can happen, and what is the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there is no need to provide this value as it is already the default one. Could you tell me where you read that such value must be set?

I don't understand what really happens with the second part of your question, as I'm not able to reproduce it (with CorsFilter, or CorsService).

Could you try using the CorsService instead? This service helps to configure the Cors feature, and is integrated in the list of services either of the Application, or the Component, for example in the constructor of the application:

```
public TestCorsApplication() {
    CorsService corsService = new CorsService();
    corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);
    corsService.setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions(true);

    getServices().add(corsService);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I did not see it in any documentation, rather in about every example I found (here too).
I could not find the origin of the duplication, I thought that perhaps it comes from somewhere inside the framework.

How can I use CorsService? now my `createInboundRoot` method, I use `CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(getContext(), router);` and `return `corsFilter`.
If switching to CorsService, how will it work, can you please provide an example?

Comment: I've updated the sample code, does it fit your need?

Comment: I still did not get how do you attach the service and my router?

Comment: you don't have to attach the service! just add it to the list of services supported by the application, cf sample code.

Comment: oh! the last line... got it now. Thanks a lot :)